# Valve for making sure only one request is active

Tags: java, rx-java2

I have a RxJava2 Flowable chain which includes some heavy computation. I want to make sure that the whole chain is only called one per request and that there is at most one active request at any given time.

Here's an example timeline:

```
-R-------R--R-R----R-------
--C....E--C....E----C....E-
```

In the above, - is idle time, R are input requests and C are computations that happen (starting with C, processing denoted by . and computation end denoted by E).

As you can see:

- The first request fires the first computation
- The second request fires the second computation
- Requests 3 and 4 are ignored as they happen while the second computation is running
- Request 5 triggers the third computation

This is what I got so far:

```
System.out.println("start");

CountDownLatch countDownLatch = new CountDownLatch(1);

AtomicBoolean valve = new AtomicBoolean(true);

Flowable.interval(100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
   .take(30)
   .filter(e -> valve.get())
   .observeOn(Schedulers.computation())
   .map(e -> {
      valve.set(false);

      System.out.println("map " + e);
      Thread.sleep(550);
      return e;
   })
   .observeOn(Schedulers.single())
   .subscribe(
      e -> {
         System.out.println("subscribe " + e);
         valve.set(true);
      },
      e -> {
         System.out.println("error " + e);
         valve.set(true);
      },
      () -> {
         System.out.println("complete");
         valve.set(true);
         countDownLatch.countDown();
      });

countDownLatch.await();

System.out.println("end");
```

So I have the flow that:

- Emits 30 integers with 100ms interval between them
- I observe that on the computation scheduler
- I set the valve to false, so that no new requests are coming in
- I map this with simulated computation time of 550ms
- I observe the results on the single scheduler
- I set the valve to true, so new requests can be processed

This seems to be working fine, but I was wondering whether there's a RxJava2-only solution that could be put instead of making use the outside of AtomicBoolean. I'm looking for that for two reasons:

- I will probably need this in a few places, so I don't want to duplicate the same code if RxJava2 already supports something out of the box
- I'm not sure if there are any consequences in terms of concurrency that would cause this not to work. E.g. I assume valve should be set to false just after the filter method, since observeOn would switch to another thread and map might run too late in case requests come in quickly one after another

Note `CountDownLatch` above is just for testing - I'm running this from my `main` method, and because there's an `observeOn`, the flow is executed on another thread, so `main` finishes before the flow executes. In real app, this won't be the case.

The real use case is an app which has a button which triggers some calculation that takes a few seconds. I don't want this to be triggered multiple times if the user clicks multiple times while the previous calculation is still in progress.

I'm fine with changing the flow if there are better solutions to this particular use case in RxJava.

Comment: RxJava is desined for parallel computations. Since you want to handle requests one by one, you need not RxJava at all. Just handle requests in a loop using separate thread.

Comment: @AlexeiKaigorodov That's not true. RxJava is designed for asynchronous and concurrent operation modes, but can do parallel and synchronous sequences as well.

Comment: Not sure what the context of this is. What and why would something call `subscribe` multiple times? Why are you blocking the caller of this code setup?

Comment: @akarnokd Not sure about the `subscribe` question, it's called only once, i.e. there's a single subscriber. For blocking the caller, if you meant `CountDownLatch` thing, that's only for testing (copied this from a `main` and because I have `observeOn`, `main` ends before the flow executes). I've edited to add these two and added the real use case as well, let me know if there's something else I need to clarify.

Comment: @akarnokd "asynchronous and concurrent" is a subset of parallel. You just narrowed my sentence, without changing its sense. Well, since topic starter wants to handle requests one by one, he does not need any asynchronous and/or concurrent library/framework.

Comment: @AlexeiKaigorodov Your said "RxJava is desined for parallel computations" which is categorically incorrect. I know because I'm the designer of RxJava 2 and you seem to be the author of a competing async library. Or is it a parallel library?

Comment: @AlexeiKaigorodov I don't want to handle requests one by one. I want to handle all requests, just making sure *one piece* of the whole flow is not executed in parallel. There's a big difference.

Comment: @akarnokd  I think parallel computations can be implemented in 2 ways - multithreading and multitasking, and multitasking is a synonym for asynchronous.  If you want to discuss this question further let's do it in other place, because this discussion would not help to solve the problem,.

Comment: @levantpied "one piece of the whole flow" - isn't it a "request"? Then "is not executed in parallel" I understand as "a request is not executed in parallel with other requests", that is, requests are executed one by one. Where am I wrong?

Comment: @AlexeiKaigorodov I've added an example, let me know if that clarifies.

Comment: @levantpied now I think I understand what you wants. I still believe this task can be implemented with pure Java, without using RxJava or any other asynchronous library. Do you want me to write an answer with the code of such solution?